# Apps randomly lose ability to make HTTP requests

Tags: network, catalina

I've started experiencing this issue where apps lose their ability to make HTTP/HTTPS requests. It happens at random, and it's happened three times in the past 2 days. All browsers, including Safari, Chrome, and Firefox fail. Other apps that can make HTTP requests like Paw, also fail. The same is true for iTunes, Spotify, and other apps that rely on HTTP calls to work.

I've determined the following:

- CLI apps like `curl` or `wget` still work and successfully make requests.
- It's not DNS issue. I can resolve domains normally using `dig`. Also, requesting sites by IP on browsers fails.
- I can ping IPs normally
- I can connect to a VPN from the network menu, but apps still can't make requests
- Rebooting does not solve the issue
- The issue persists even if I boot in safe mode
- I've tested turning the os firewall on/off
- I have [LuLu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) installed (and had it for months), but it's been disabled for a few weeks. I don't have any other third party security apps.
- TCP saturation doesn't appear to be the case. `lsof -n -i TCP` only shows about 25 connections (also remember `curl` works..)

I discovered that deleting the Ethernet adapter and re-creating it from the networking menu fixes the issue immediately. However, it doesn't stop it from happening again.

I suspect this is related to a recent macOS update, but I don't know how to isolate the problem.

This is happening on an iMac Pro 2017 with Catalina (10.15.2)

Comment: I've had the same issue and have been able to fix it by restarting networkserviceproxy. Run this in the Terminal.app and then see if you can connect to http: `pkill -SIGHUP networkserviceproxy`.